# Lazarus DBLookupCombobox can not convert null to int64 for data submission

Tags: lazarus

I have been using Lazarus 2.x with Firebird 3 (via flamerobin) and i try to commit records via TSQLConnection, TSQLQuery, TDataSource in a data module.

I run the following script successfully in order to configure initially DBLookupCombobox, where the records are displayed without any problem.

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  appeals.SQLQuery4.Close;
  appeals.SQLQuery4.SQL.Text:='select id,fullname from promoter';

  appeals.SQLQuery4.Open;

  appeals.DataSource2.DataSet:=appeals.SQLQuery4;
  DBLookupComboBox1.ListSource:=appeals.DataSource2;
  DBLookupComboBox1.ScrollListDataset:=True;
  DBLookupComboBox1.Style:=csDropDownList;
  DBLookupComboBox1.KeyField:='id';
  DBLookupComboBox1.DataField:='id';
  DBLookupComboBox1.ListField:='fullname';    

  end;
```

Afterwards i use the following snippet for record submission:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  appeals.SQLTransaction1.Active:=false;

  appeals.SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='UPDATE appeals set name=:name,date_entry=:entry,date_suspended=:suspended,'+
  'date_court=:court,date_judgement=:judgement,promoter_id=:code where id='+IntToStr(row_num);

  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('name').AsString:=Trim(Edit1.Text);
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('entry').AsDate:=DateTimePicker1.Date;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('suspended').AsDate:=IncDay(DateTimePicker1.Date,10);
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('court').AsDate:=DateTimePicker2.Date;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('judgement').AsDate:=IncDay(DateTimePicker2.Date,20);
  appeals.SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('code').AsInteger:=DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue;

  appeals.SQLTransaction1.StartTransaction;
  appeals.SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  appeals.SQLTransaction1.Commit;
  Application.MessageBox('Record submission with success !', 'Information', MB_ICONINFORMATION);                               

 end;
```

I have also attached the following script in Form Create event without any luck from [wiki article](https://wiki.freepascal.org/TDBLookupComboBox).

```
If (DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue = Null) And (appeals.SQLQuery4.RecordCount > 0) Then
    DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue := appeals.SQLQuery4.FieldByName('id').AsVariant;
```

Any idea would help me a lot regarding DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue where the following error appears!

[image]

I would like to update the fields of a table via DBLookupCombobox (foreign key) that loads data from another table, two datetimepickers and edit control.

[image]

Regards

Comment: I think you need to expand the code in your q to a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because your "The problem beings ..." para does not provide sufficient info for anyone to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have also provided a wiki article link where i use this code in form create event. The problem has to do with KeyValue submission of  DBLookupComboBox where its value is NULL.

Comment: Try to assign `ListSource` before any other `DBLookupComboBox1` initializations (as in the wiki example).

Comment: Sorry, but saying "the problem has to do with ..." doesn't throw any light on what the problem actually is.

Comment: I have exactly followed the wiki steps and still the problem remains. I have posted the exact error message that i get and hope to throw light on my problem nature. Your help is significant to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that before `appeals.SQLTransaction1.Active:=false`, i have to store `DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue` into a local variable as database connection afterwards is lost and thus there is not any value to DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue but NULL.

Therefore i have to use that local variable into my SQL query to update the appropriate record.

I should be more careful next time!